# Can δῖος legitimately be translated as "boundless?"

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, homer

Homer uses the set phrases ἅλα δῖαν and ἠῶ δῖαν to describe the sea and the dawn. Some 19th century [commentators](https://archive.org/details/firstsixbooksofh01home/page/150/mode/2up) and translators (Buckley) think δῖαν should be read here as "boundless." The Cambridge Greek Lexicon that my wife gave me as an early Christmas present says, "(of air, sea, earth, dawn) divine, holy Hom. Hes. S. E. A. Emp. E. Call. [or perh. bright]." They conspicuously omit "boundless." Anthon's commentary says:

> To be rendered here 'boundless.' Literally 'divine.' The idea of boundless extent and vast energy is here transferred from the deity to one of the noblest of his works.

This sounds to me suspiciously like an attempt to impose a modern monotheistic Christian point of view on the ancients. Actually, I don't think the Greek gods were themselves "boundless," just able to see and act at great distances.

Is there any evidence in other authors that it really makes sense to read this as "boundless?" The list of abbreviations in the Cambridge lexicon translates to Homer, Hesiod, Sophocles, Euripides, Aeschylus, Empedocles, and Callimachus.

"Bright" seems less anachronistic to me, since the etymology of δῖος has to do with the sky. This would apply less to "earth," but I haven't been able to locate any examples in Homer where the adjective is applied to the earth.

Comment: Anthon's "the deity" is puzzling -- which deity? (Which is to say that I agree with your point, and don't know of any warrant for translating δῖος as "boundless".)

Comment: If the deity is Poseidon, I think it is strange to describe the sea as one of his works.  As far as I recall, he did not create the sea.

Comment: Boundless is a strange word for the ancient Greeks to apply to either the dawn or the sea.  The dawn disappeared every morning, and the seas they knew best were definitely bounded.